# for(each) ending before going through all of the list

Tags: c#, database, for-loop, foreach

I also tried using for instead of foreach (of course change the inside of the ()) but it still didn't work. What can I Do?
tableSiblings is initialized

When running the code, it only goes through a small part of the rows in tableSiblings.Rows instead of all of it

```
enter codsSiblings = dal.GetDataSet("Select * From Siblings");
// Go through the table:
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in tableSiblings.Rows)
{
    // If this is a new row:
    if ((row.Cells["siblingID"].Value ?? string.Empty).ToString() == string.Empty.ToString())
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
    else
    {
        // Go through the database:
        foreach (DataRow dr in dsSiblings.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            // If a sibling with the same ID exists:
            if ((row.Cells["siblingID"].Value ?? string.Empty).ToString() == dr["siblingID"].ToString())
            {
                DoSomethingElse();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
dal.UpdateDataSet(dsSiblings);
```

Comment: How did you verify it does this? Did you debug it? What happened in the middle that caused it to stop before the end?

Comment: What do you mean?
I ran the code and it just went through a part of the tableSiblings.Rows

Comment: I don’t know how more clearly ask how do you know this happens. You claim the loop doesn’t finish. How do you know that?

Comment: I used a breakpoint so the application would stop when it reaches the start of the that method and used F10 to step forward and saw that the loops doesn't finish

Comment: So it just hangs? Where does it hang?

Comment: it doesn't hang. it's breaking out of the foreach or the for before finishing

Comment: At which exact point?

Comment: Try adding tableSiblings.Rows to a watch and see how many rows you actually see

Comment: How do I do that?